# Postgres COALESCE inside nullif for 2 different fields

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, coalesce

I am new to SQL and POSTGRES and had a quick question.  Right now I have 2 different tables one with car info and one with partial car info and I would like to sort on car.vin OR partial_car.vin depending if either exists and sending all nulls/empty strings to the end of the sort.  Currently my ORDER BY statement looks like:

`ORDER BY nullif(coalesce(car.vin, partial_car.partial_vin), '') asc nulls last limit 50 offset 0`

My expectation for this is that coalesce will take the first non null value and use that for sorting or it will return null and send that to the end.  My results so far I haven't been able to make sense of.  There are null values being placed in between actual values etc..  If I make this change coalesce(car.vin, '') again I see it work properly.  Anyone have an ideas as to why this is the behavior?  Let me know if you need something more from me.

Comment: The reason is because we allow the flexibility of keeping full car or only partial car.  Depending on what we find it powers which forms we would show the client next.  Wasn't my design choice but thats what it is :)

Comment: Well, this kind of requirement should be moved to the application layer. I would hate working at your place. Your boss / coworker is hiding his mistake by burning your neurones. Quit that job.

Comment: @jkerivan That should work fine. The only way I can imagine for "empty" rows to occur in between is that there are values containing only spaces or other invisible characters. Try putting a `trim` around the `coalesce`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am seeing this values come back as null, but I will try the trim.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It was human error on my end.  The object being sent to client was not being populated properly with partial data.  So sorting was correct but was seeing blanks due to those values not being present.